# Need online resources to compare the pronunciation in Latin, Old French and Old English

Tags: pronunciation, latin, resource-request, online-resources, old-french

I'm looking for resources giving old French pronunciation, for instance as IPA.

I know that the pronunciation of old French is quite regular, but I cannot find a dictionary with pronunciations.

I need that to make linguistics researches, see how the language evolved, understanding the difference in the spelling of a same word, and how they evolved. And how pronunciation evolved in a language. And how a word evolved from he Latin root in the modern language.

For this purpose, I'm also interested in good online old French dictionaries, and an old English pronunciation dictionary.

Meaning of my question = **I'm looking for resources to compare the pronunciation and their evolution between Latin, Old French and Old English.**

Just to know: Does a dictionary comparing old French and English words (derived) exist?